# Need help finding out name of part

Tags: ford, ranger

I need help finding out name of this part on my 1998 Ford Ranger.

Please help me find out.
Thank you.

[image: cruise control throttle actuator]

Answer (score 1):

Cruise control throttle cable/linkage/actuator.